# Android layout background color effecting all widgets beneath

Tags: android, android-layout

When setting the top level xml layout background color why do all the widgets beneath like buttons and edittext take on the same color?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/myyarns_scroll"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/orange5"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:isScrollContainer="false"
android:paddingLeft="2dp"
android:paddingRight="2dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout0"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/myyarns_scan_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Bar Code"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/myyarns_add_dialog_scan"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Scan" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

This is how it's displayed in Android Studio and on a device.

[image: This is how it's displayed in Android Studio and on a device.]

What do I need to set in the layout XML to prevent all the widgets beneath being painted over by the layout background color?

Comment: i think best way is to define style for buttons, editText, textView, ...and set their background is their styles

Answer (score 0):

`

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

`

in styles file give   @color/black every view background will be black by default if you want to override it use for particular view android:background="@color/orange5"